# The connective ! has truth table... Show that the connective is not adequate.

Tags: logic

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
P & Q & P!Q \\ \hline
T & T & F \\
T & F & T \\
F & T & F \\
F & F & F
\end{array}$$

I think this should be proved using induction but I have no idea where to start..
Thanks

Comment: What does adequate mean in ths context?

Comment: A set S of connectives is adequate if and only if there are formulas involving only connectives from S which are logically equivalent to (p1^p2), (p1vp2) and (-p1) [not p]

Comment: I showed how to do this kind of induction proof over here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670531/show-that-s-wedge-leftrightarrow-are-not-an-adequate-set-of-connectives/670931#670931

Comment: I don't follow it.

Answer (score 3):

The $False!False \rightarrow False$ is where you should encounter problems. Any formula with just $!$, when you plug in all values $False$, will return $False$. This means you cannot express all truth tables with just $!$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $E$ is any expression built up from $!$ and from $p$.  You can show, by induction, that when $p$ is false, $E$ is also false.  But then $E$ is *not* equivalent to $\lnot p$, because $\lnot p$ is true when $p$ is false.  So no expression built up from just $!$ and $p$ can express $\lnot p$, and therefore $!$ is not adequate.

Comment: how would i use induction for this?

Comment: Let's say that an expression is "good" if it has the property that it is false whenever all its atoms are false.  For example $A\land B$ is good, but $\lnot A$ is not good.  Let $P(n)$ be the claim that every expression with $n$ or fewer $!$ operators is good.  $P(0)$ is true because an expression with no operators is an atom, and atomic expressions are good.  Then using induction to prove $P(n)$ for all $n$.